# fish: Unknown command: uname when using custom python command

Tags: python, pytube

I made a python script to download youtube videos

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from pytube import YouTube

for arg in sys.argv:
    video = YouTube(sys.argv[1])
    video.streams.get_by_itag(18).download("/home/gabrielz/Downloads/")
```

And then I followed this tutorial: https://dbader.org/blog/how-to-make-command-line-commands-with-python

But when ever I run it I get this error

> fish: Unknown command: uname ~/.config/fish/conf.d/done.fish (line
> 90):  else if uname -a | string match --quiet --ignore-case --regex
> microsoft ^ in function '__done_get_focused_window_id' called on line
> 1 of file ~/.config/fish/conf.d/done.fish in command substitution
> called on line 195 of file ~/.config/fish/conf.d/done.fish in function
> '__done_started' with arguments 'download
> [https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=gjwTHJbpJyk'](https://www.youtube.com/watch%5C?v=gjwTHJbpJyk%27) in event handler:
> handler for generic event “fish_preexec” fish: No matches for wildcard
> “https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjwTHJbpJyk”. See `help expand`.
> download https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjwTHJbpJyk

(Im Just using a random youtube video) Can Anyone help me figure out whats wrong. By the way im using garuda linux.

Comment: Change your login shell from fish to bash, login again, and check if you get the same error. Also make sure that `ls -l /bin/sh` doesn't show fish.

Comment: Add the directory containing the uname command to your $PATH, and then try again.